# What type of timestamps might these be?

Tags: c#, android, xml, windows-phone, sms

In Android, I'm trying to import text message backup file (in XML format, exported from a Windows Phone).  Now, the issue I am facing is with the time stamps attributed to each of the messages. The fact is, I don't know what type of timestamps these are and how can I convert them to human-readable date/time. Here are a few timestamps and their equivalent in human time, extracted from my Windows Phone:

```
130785979762200000 -> the 12th of June 2015, 6:52 PM GMT+2, 4:52 PM GMT
130785978668070000 -> the 12th of June 2015, 6:51 PM GMT+2, 4:51 PM GMT
130785978597700000 -> the 12th of June 2015, 6:50 PM GMT+2, 4:50 PM GMT
130776657503200000 -> the 1st of June 2015, 11:55 PM GMT+2, 9:55 PM GMT
```

I can give more if needed. Also, the format I am trying to output to, is that of the SMS Backup&Restore app from Google Play Store (#1 result when searching for "message backup"), which is as follows, and neither this, nor the Windows Phone format, seem familiar to me:

```
1434616221869 -> the 18th of June 2015, 11:30 AM GMT+2, 9:30 GMT
1434616248250 -> the 18th of June 2015, 11:30 AM GMT+2, 9:30 GMT
1434616275261 -> the 18th of June 2015, 11:31 AM GMT+2, 9:31 GMT
```

Also, as I believe from studying the formats that they clearly store the seconds too, hence the difference between the first and second entry in the Android list. The same on WP, although I haven't find yet two messages sent at the same time (speaking of hour, minutes and date).

So, I am looking for information about various information about timestamps, maybe a list of timestamp systems.

Comment: that is the long representation of the date.

Comment: epoch time. http://www.epochconverter.com/ first one is micro seconds second one is seconds.

Comment: The web site states the first one (130785979762200000 ) is Sun, 12 Jun 2011 06:23:17 GMT, but I will look more into it, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the first one is indeed microseconds, the count starts on January, the 1st, 1601, 0:00:00 UTC, specific to NTFS file system. Now looking into the second one...

Comment: And the second one is a simple Unix timestamp indeed, in milliseconds. Thanks @corn3lius for your help, you should have answered this so I could mark this as solved and give you the 'thumbs up'. Thanks again, pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Those timestamps look like they are Epoch time.

Also known as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

They can sometimes be written as milliseconds, where they are 1000x, depending on the precision of the logging tool.

Here is great tool to convert those into readable dates  http://www.epochconverter.com/